# I cannot loop json object on swift xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swifty-json

I'm learning swift and objective-c. I want to extract the "show_name" in my Json for all shows.

This is my json :

```
  {
"data": {
    "12 Monkeys": {
        "air_by_date": 0,
        "anime": 0,
        "cache": {
            "banner": 1,
            "poster": 1
        },
        "indexerid": 272644,
        "language": "en",
        "network": "Syfy",
        "next_ep_airdate": "",
        "paused": 0,
        "quality": "SD",
        "show_name": "12 Monkeys",
        "sports": 0,
        "status": "Continuing",
        "subtitles": 1,
        "tvdbid": 272644
    },
    "2 Broke Girls": {
        "air_by_date": 0,
        "anime": 0,
        "cache": {
            "banner": 1,
            "poster": 1
        },
        "indexerid": 248741,
        "language": "en",
        "network": "CBS",
        "next_ep_airdate": "2016-10-10",
        "paused": 0,
        "quality": "SD",
        "show_name": "2 Broke Girls",
        "sports": 0,
        "status": "Continuing",
        "subtitles": 0,
        "tvdbid": 248741
    },
    "American Horror Story": {
        "air_by_date": 0,
        "anime": 0,
        "cache": {
            "banner": 1,
            "poster": 1
        },
        "indexerid": 250487,
        "language": "en",
        "network": "FX (US)",
        "next_ep_airdate": "2016-09-14",
        "paused": 0,
        "quality": "SD",
        "show_name": "American Horror Story",
        "sports": 0,
        "status": "Continuing",
        "subtitles": 0,
        "tvdbid": 250487
    },
```

This is my code and I use swiftyJson :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


  let baseURL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8083/api/api/?cmd=shows&sort=name&paused=0"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    getJSON()
}

func getJSON(){
    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
    { (data, response, error) -> Void in

       if error == nil {

        let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
        print(swiftyJSON)
        let title = swiftyJSON["data"]["Sense8"]["show_name"]
        print(title)



    }else {
     print("there was an error")

    }

  }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `swiftyJSON` is an array of `JSON`, (i.e. `[JSON]`), therefore you are not able to access it by subscript.
You can parse it as follow :

```
 if let dataArray = swiftyJSON.array{
      for json in dataArray {

            // data information

            let showName = json["show_name"].stringValue
            let status = json["status"].stringValue
            let subtitles = json["subtitles"].stringValue
            print(showName)
            print(status)
            print(subtitles)
          }
}
```